# Create new recordset by executing query on another recordset in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA 2003. Is it possible to create new recordset by executing query on another recordset ?

The query could look like "select * from recordset1 where "

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply an SQL query to an existing recordset, you can use the (limited) [.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275540%28BTS.10%29.aspx) method, iterate the rows and apply your own criteria or simply modify the query you used to open the 1st recordset to include the additional criteria.